# the connection between $\gamma_m(a)$ and $\gamma_m(b)$ when $a\cdot b\equiv 1\pmod m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> show the connection between the order of $a$ $\gamma_m(a)$ and the order of $b$ $\gamma_m(b)$ when
>
> $$a\cdot b\equiv 1\pmod m$$

I took $a=5$ and $b=4$

$$5\cdot 4\equiv 1\pmod{19}$$

$$\gamma_m(a)=9\text{ and } \gamma_m(b)=9$$

So I think that alaways $\gamma_m(a)=\gamma(b)$ when $a\cdot b\equiv 1\pmod m$

Is there a more formal way to show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has $a^{\gamma_m(a)}\equiv 1$ and $b^{\gamma_m(b)}\equiv 1\pmod{m}$. Multiplying the two and assuming without loss of generality that $\gamma_m{a}\gt \gamma_m(b)$ we can write

$$a^{\gamma_m(a)-\gamma_m(b)}\left(a\cdot b\right)^{\gamma_m(b)}\equiv 1\pmod{m}$$

This means $a^\alpha\equiv 1\pmod{m}$ with $\gamma_m(a)-\gamma_m(b)=\alpha\lt \gamma_m(a)$ which is a contradiction. So the orders are equal.

Answer (score 1):

$a$ and $b$ are each other's multiplicative inverse, i.e. $b=a^{-1} \mod m$. So the equation is $a\cdot a^{-1} = 1 \mod m$. Clearly, if you raise $1$ to a power, it remains $1$, so the same should be true of $a\cdot a^{-1}$. Suppose the order of $a$ is $\gamma(a)$, so $a^{\gamma(a)}=1\mod m$. Then

$$1 = a\cdot a^{-1} = (a\cdot a^{-1})^{\gamma(a)} = (a)^{\gamma(a)}\cdot (a^{-1})^{\gamma(a)} = 1 \cdot (a^{-1})^{\gamma(a)} = (a^{-1})^{\gamma(a)} = 1$$

So the orders are equal. $\square$